# How to do Grouping of NodeItems in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input xml :

```
<Root>
    <RootHeader>Header</RootHeader>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>Header001</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>1</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>2</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>101</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>3</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>101</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>4</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>5</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>102</value>
    </Reference>
</Root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Root>
    <RootHeader>Header</RootHeader>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>Header001</value>
    </Reference>

    <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
    <NodeNumber>1</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
    <NodeNumber>2</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>101</value>
    </Reference>

    <GroupingSequenceNumber>2</GroupingSequenceNumber>
    <NodeNumber>3</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <GroupingSequenceNumber>3</GroupingSequenceNumber>
    <NodeNumber>4</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
    <NodeNumber>5</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>102</value>
    </Reference>
</Root>
```

How to do grouping based on Root/Reference/Value and add Grouping Sequence Number in output?

Reference in header should be excluded in grouping. Means Grouping should start after occurance of NodeNumber.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: It's a good start that you have supplied a use case. But I still don't understand your requirements. What are the groups and what is the grouping condition? What is the signficance of GroupingSequenceNumber? Are the Reference nodes supposed to be accrued to thier previous sibling NodeNumber nodes?

Comment: Hello..let me explain as per input sample, Root/Reference/Value contains values 100,101,102...so grouping should be applied on this value..and  GroupingSequenceNumber will contain sequence no of that, say for Root/Reference/Value = 100, GroupingSequenceNumber = 1,2,3[occurences of 100]

Comment: Your explaination doesn't match the provided sample. In the input, nodes 1 and 4 have value 100. But in your provided output, they are not even grouped together.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me..i have corrected expected ouput

Comment: This is a straight-forward case of Muenchian grouping. There are hundreds of questions on StackOverflow which are only a slight variation of this question. Of course, some-one will give you a specific answer shortly, but it would benefit you to search and read previous questions. Search on Muenchian or perhaps 'xslt grouping'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to your previous question of [Grouping of xml nodes in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354471/grouping-of-xml-nodes-in-xslt-1-0)

In this case though, you really want to match the **NodeNumber** elements, and count them by looking at the value following **Reference** elements.

```
<xsl:variable name="Ref" select="following-sibling::Reference[1]/value"/>
<GroupingSequenceNumber>
   <xsl:number count="NodeNumber[following-sibling::Reference[1]/value = $Ref]"/>
</GroupingSequenceNumber>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="NodeNumber">
      <xsl:variable name="Ref" select="following-sibling::Reference[1]/value"/>
      <GroupingSequenceNumber>
         <xsl:number count="NodeNumber[following-sibling::Reference[1]/value = $Ref]"/>
      </GroupingSequenceNumber>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample input document, the following is output

```
<Root>
   <RootHeader>Header</RootHeader>
   <Reference>
      <name>RefName</name>
      <value>Header001</value>
   </Reference>
   <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
   <NodeNumber>1</NodeNumber>
   <Reference>
      <name>RefName</name>
      <value>100</value>
   </Reference>
   <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
   <NodeNumber>2</NodeNumber>
   <Reference>
      <name>RefName</name>
      <value>101</value>
   </Reference>
   <GroupingSequenceNumber>2</GroupingSequenceNumber>
   <NodeNumber>3</NodeNumber>
   <Reference>
      <name>RefName</name>
      <value>101</value>
   </Reference>
   <GroupingSequenceNumber>2</GroupingSequenceNumber>
   <NodeNumber>4</NodeNumber>
   <Reference>
      <name>RefName</name>
      <value>100</value>
   </Reference>
   <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
   <NodeNumber>5</NodeNumber>
   <Reference>
      <name>RefName</name>
      <value>102</value>
   </Reference>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="kRefs" match="Reference[preceding-sibling::NodeNumber]" use="value" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="
      @* | node()[not(self::Reference[preceding-sibling::NodeNumber])][not(self::NodeNumber)]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="
        Reference[preceding-sibling::NodeNumber]
                 [generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRefs',value)[1])]">
       <xsl:comment>Start of group for value <xsl:value-of select="value" /></xsl:comment> 
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kRefs',value)" />            
       <xsl:comment>End of group</xsl:comment>   
    </xsl:for-each>               
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Reference[preceding-sibling::NodeNumber]" >
  <GroupingSequenceNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></GroupingSequenceNumber>
  <xsl:copy-of select=".|preceding-sibling::NodeNumber[1]" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to this input...

```
<Root>
    <RootHeader>Header</RootHeader>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>Header001</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>1</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>2</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>101</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>3</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>101</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>4</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </Reference>

    <NodeNumber>5</NodeNumber>
    <Reference>
        <name>RefName</name>
        <value>102</value>
    </Reference>
</Root>
```

...yields...

```
<Root>
  <RootHeader>Header</RootHeader>
  <Reference>
    <name>RefName</name>
    <value>Header001</value>
  </Reference>
  <!--Start of group for value 100-->
  <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
  <NodeNumber>1</NodeNumber>
  <Reference>
    <name>RefName</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </Reference>
  <GroupingSequenceNumber>2</GroupingSequenceNumber>
  <NodeNumber>4</NodeNumber>
  <Reference>
    <name>RefName</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </Reference>
  <!--End of group-->
  <!--Start of group for value 101-->
  <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
  <NodeNumber>2</NodeNumber>
  <Reference>
    <name>RefName</name>
    <value>101</value>
  </Reference>
  <GroupingSequenceNumber>2</GroupingSequenceNumber>
  <NodeNumber>3</NodeNumber>
  <Reference>
    <name>RefName</name>
    <value>101</value>
  </Reference>
  <!--End of group-->
  <!--Start of group for value 102-->
  <GroupingSequenceNumber>1</GroupingSequenceNumber>
  <NodeNumber>5</NodeNumber>
  <Reference>
    <name>RefName</name>
    <value>102</value>
  </Reference>
  <!--End of group-->
</Root>
```